# Launch python script from node.js browser application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a Node.js web application that integrates the DALL-E API to generate images based on user input. The application is functional, and I can successfully retrieve images from the DALL-E API. Additionally, I have a Python script that can convert images to G-code.

Now, I want to link these two functionalities together, but I'm facing challenges in the implementation. Here's what I have done so far:

I have built the Node.js web application that communicates with the DALL-E API to fetch images based on user input.
I have a Python script that performs G-code conversion from images.
My objective is to take the image obtained from the DALL-E API and pass it to the Python script for G-code conversion. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to achieve this integration. Here are my specific questions:

How can I efficiently transfer the image data from the Node.js application to the Python script for G-code conversion?
Where should I store the Python script within the Node.js project directory structure?
My initial idea was to contact the server shell from the Node.js application and instruct it to execute the Python script. However, I'm struggling to implement this concept effectively.

Comment: Did you [search for "launch python from node" at all](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=launch+python+from+node&cat=web&pl=ext-ff&language=english&extVersion=1.3.0)? There a lots of results.

Comment: Yes, but none of those solution worked, I can't find an example that works with a browser app...

Comment: Well I guess you need to explain what a "node.js browser application" is. Are you talking about Electron?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "*How can I efficiently transfer the image data?*" - the lowest common denominator will be to save it as a file, pass the file path to the python script, and read the file. In what format does the DALL-E API return the image data? If it's an image URL, the most efficient way would be to pass the URL to the python script and download it with python. "*Where should I store the Python script within the Node.js project directory structure?*" - doesn't matter. Or: don't put it in the node.js project at all, treat it like an external program (which it is).

Comment: DALL-E gives me back a b64 json file. The problem is I'd like to automaticly launch the python script after the image has been downloaded